# Is it possible to retrieve a users browser history via the API?

Tags: api, browser-history, google-admin-sdk, chromebook

We are moving to Chromebooks in our school and would like to know if it's possible to retrieve the users browser history.  Every month we perform a device check in where the teacher physically inspects each students device for anything "suspicious".  This generally entails looking at their browser history for things like pornographic or other unsavory URLs.

I would be very handy to build a nightly process that slurps up the student's browser history, checks it for any anomalies, and reports that to the administration.  Is this possible?  Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is fully supported yet. [chrome.history](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/history#method-search) from Chrome API can only 
 interact with the browser's record of visited pages. You can add, remove, and query for URLs in the browser's history; that's as far as API goes.